# Managing Services in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service

I'm in the beginning stages of writing a turn-based game for Android. Currently, I'm planning for it to be single player, where the player plays against AI's. It will be a fairly complex game, and since it is turn-based, a lot of calculations and work will have to be done after each turn the player takes (the AI's each have to compute and "take their turn"). I'm currently entertaining the idea of doing all that work in a `service`. Once the player ends their turn, the apps main activity will create a new service. The service will do all the calculations for the AI's (in a separate thread from the main Activity), and the main Activity will show some loading animation indicating that the AI players are "thinking."

The reason I want to take this approach is so that, if the user closes the app while the AI's are still "taking their turn," the service will still be able to do all the calculations, even if the main activity is killed by the system.

I'm still ironing out a lot of the details, but I've come across a few questions. Consider the case where the user ends their turn, the service is created and started, and while the service is happily running, the user closes the app, the app's main activity is destroyed by the system, and then the user decides to open the app again. When the app opens, the following needs to happen:

- The main activity needs to check and see if the service is still running, and if it is...
- Once the service finishes its job, it needs to tell the main activity (provided the user reopened the app and the main activity is currently running) that it is finished before it is destroyed.

So I have the following questions:

1. Is there a way for my activity to check and see if the service is still running?*
2. Is there a way for the service to tell the main activity that it is finished, without the main activity having to poll?

*I've seen some answers to similar questions suggesting the use of global variables, but since I've been told time and time again by countless professors and colleagues to avoid global variables as much as I can, I'm trying to see if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way for my activity to check and see if the service is still running?*

Below is one of the solutions I have found

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

It loops through all running services and returns `true` if your service is found

> Is there a way for the service to tell the main activity that it is finished, without the main activity having to poll?

For this, you can use `LocalBroadcastManager`. When the service is about to stop send a `LocalBroadcast` from the service and listen for the `LocalBroadcastManager` in the `Activity` you want

In `Service`

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new Intent("SERVICE_STOPPED"))
```

In `Activity`

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                   //task to do on service stop event 
    }
};
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("SERVICE_STOPPED"));
```